# Results Returns Index Array is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, axios, cheerio

I have a question that I use Axios and Cheerio to get other web data about and take it into an array. Here I have an array

```
linkURLG = []
```

When `console.log(linkURLG)` it still releases the results but when I use it with
`console.log(linkURLG.length)` then it returns to 0 even though the array has 21 length
Where do I ask the problem and how to solve it? Thanks for reading.

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const fs = require('fs')


let linkURLG = []
async function getData() {
    try {
            const url = 'https://viblo.asia/newest'
            const { data } = await axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            // headers: {
            //     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.88 Safari/537.36'
            // }
        })
        const $ = cheerio.load(data)
        const elementUrl = $('.post-feed-item')
        const dataGet = []
        const linkUrls = []
        $(elementUrl).each((index, element) => {
            const author = $(element).find('span.el-popover__reference-wrapper').text().trim()
            const authorAvt = $(element).find('a.d-flex.mr-05 > img').attr('src')
            const title = $(element).find('h3.word-break.mr-05').text()
            const url = 'https://viblo.asia' + $(element).find('h3.word-break.mr-05 > a').attr('href')
            const view = $(element).find('div.stats > span').first().text().trim()
            dataGet[index] = {author, authorAvt, title, url, view}
            linkUrls[index] = {url}
            linkURLG[index] = {url}
        })
        // console.log(dataGet)
        // console.log(linkUrls)
        document.getElementById('renderer-contain').innerHTML = dataGet.map(dataGet => `
    
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-avt">
                <div class="card-avt-img"><img src="${dataGet.authorAvt}"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-contain">
                <div class="author"><span>Author</span> ${dataGet.author}</div>
                <div class="card-contain-title"><a href="${dataGet.url}">${dataGet.title}</a></div>
                <div class="view"><span>Lượt xem:</span> ${dataGet.view}</div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        `).join('')

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
getData()

console.log(linkURLG)

async function getContent() {
    try {
        const url = 'https://viblo.asia/newest'
            const { data } = await axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            // headers: {
            //     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.88 Safari/537.36'
            // }
        })
        const $ = cheerio.load(data)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

```css
/* styles.css */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

/* Add styles here to customize the appearance of your app */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#renderer-contain {
    display: flex;
    gap: 5px;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 10px 10px;
}

.card {
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    /* color: white; */
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10px;
}

.card-avt {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-avt-img > img {
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.card-contain {
    display: flex;
    gap: 5px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.author > span {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.329);
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    border: .5px solid rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.329);
    color: rgba(2, 91, 91, 0.566);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.author {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 2px;
}


.card-contain .view {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.card-contain-title > a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(71, 71, 255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"> -->
    <link href="./styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>getApi</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="renderer-contain"></div>
    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the unresolved promise. if you await the completion of getData the console log should display the length correctly.

```js
await getData()
```

Comment: Thank you I understand, I have solved it.